# Ubuntu 13.10 32 bit or 64? Lenovo ThinkPad E531 - i3-3110m - 8gb ram

Tags: 13.10, hardware, thinkpad, versions

I wonder what version of Ubuntu should I install: 32 or 64 bit?

My hardware:

- ThinkPad E531
- i3-3110m
- 8gb ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official Intel page about your processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/65700/intel-core-i3-3110m-processor-3m-cache-2_40-ghz), it is **64-bit.** As such, it's optimal to install the 64-bit version of **ubuntu**.